# Run Spring Boot jar from standard Java application

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependencies

I have a large application with a database, Swing UI etc. Now I want to add a REST API for this application. Spring Boot allows easy generation of a REST API with useful features such as OpenApi documentation and authentication.

However when I run the Spring Boot application from within the large non Spring Boot application the Spring Boot application gets confused by the dependencies of the parent application and fails to run.

So my requirement is this: run a Spring Boot application from withing a non Spring Boot application without dependency interference from the parent application. I am currently running the Spring Boot application by adding the executable jar as a dependency and then calling
`org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(new String[0]);`
to run the Spring Boot application. I am not set on this way of doing it and any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can have separate modules within the same project and have a separate build.gradle files for each of the modules.

Comment: @dkb I have tried that, but was unable to see how to run the REST API module in the other module. Don't want to make the second module a Spring Boot application as it is a large project that would take time to convert. I would be happy to have 2 modules as long as I can run the Spring Boot module from within the standard Java module. The reason that I want to to this is that I need to provide the data for the REST API from the standard non Spring Boot module

Comment: you can export the pure java module's jar and add that as dependency on spring boot's module

Comment: There will still be the dependency issue. The pure Java project has a number of dependencies such as database, logging etc which interfere with Spring Boot as Spring Boot tries to autoconfigure those. I need to make Spring Boot ignore all the dependencies from the pure Java project

Comment: IMO the cleanest way to achieve this is, as others have stated, totally separate these modules (projects even!) - make artifacts and logic independent from each other. It will ease deployments and further development - atomicity pays off :) 
You've stated earlier that decoupling them would take you lots of time - are you sure it's not worth it?
Another thing you wrote is that this REST module depends on desktop one - why so? If this is matter of some configuration I bet you can achieve the same thing with secured configuration endpoints on your REST app that your desktop client will use

Comment: I am new to Spring Boot so let me know if it seems like I am missing something obvious here. The REST module depends on the plain Java module as the plain Java module provides the data for the REST API. My idea is to pass in a DataProvider object from the plain Java module so that when the /getsomestuff url is called I have a DataProvider object in the rest controller class which has a corresponding method getSomeStuff() which will get the data which will then be diplayed as JSON at the /getsomestuff endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring is a huge collection of highly configurable software libraries that can be used to setup (among other things) REST API endpoints and OpenAPI documentation and UI.

Spring Boot is a project to simplify the process of using these libraries by applying an opinionated view of how to run them within a standalone process.

By asking how to run a Spring Boot application within a larger application you are trying to get the benefit of the opinionated setup while violating the assumptions that the setup is based on. I guess in theory it might be possible using some sort of handrolled classloader isolation, but once you've solved the dependency problem you'll probably end up with class version conflicts, issues with configuration locations, etc. In short if it is possible at all the effort of doing so would negate the benefit.

There are two ways of resolving the issue.

1. Use Spring Boot to build your API as a standalone process. Configure the new process to talk to the same database as the existing application. If neccessary factor out any code common to both the existing application and the API (JPA entities, DAO classes etc) into a shared library. If you go with this option you will have the overhead of having to manage multiple kinds of process in your production environment, which is more complex - but has advantages in terms of decoupling scaling, release cycles, restart times. See the debate on microservices (https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html).
2. Use the Spring libraries that provide REST and OpenAPI features as part of your existing application, without using Spring Boot. You'll need to have SpringMVC set up in order to use @RestController annotated classes. If your existing application is a web application that's not too bad (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html). If it's not run in a webserver already you'll have to launch the SpringMVC framework in an embedded webserver (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/create-a-java-web-application-using-embedded-tomcat). There's a good article on adding OpenAPI to an MVC application here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation.

Comment: It seems like it is not a good idea to try run a Spring Boot application from within a standard Java application. Either go all Spring Boot or no Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply exclude auto-configure dependencies. Here is an informative link https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-boot

Here is a code snippet of how to exclude when applications get started.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PayPalApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

or the other ways

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

I want to share another Spring Framework dependencies https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-framework

Comment: I tried this but there are a lot of issues such as `@ConditionalOnClass did not find required class` it seems better to not use Spring Boot